# Define subnets for multi-az elb deployments with boxfuse

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc, cloudcaptain

I noticed there is already a

```
-subnet=...              The AWS subnet to deploy to (single instance apps only)
```

parameter but not for ELB-based deployments, yet. Is it already possible to define which vpc/subnets should be used for a deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently all subnets of the default VPC are associated with the automatically created auto-scaling groups. The auto-scaling groups will then launch instances across them in a balanced fashion.

Please file a feature request if you need more control: https://github.com/cloudcaptainsh/cloudcaptain/issues